# Do SQL triggers run sequentially?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, transactions

Okay, I've been working on SQL since quite some time now and have written all sorts of complex queries. But somehow, I can't grasp the basic concepts related to a couple of things.

My questions are:

1. Do SQL queries run in parallel? 
   (I think they don't because you can't have 2 queries changing data in the same table at the same time, right? You wouldn't be able to ensure the primary key or auto increment or unique index that way, right?)
2. How do triggers work? e.g. I recently wrote a trigger to prevent double bookings for doctors in mysql. It's a BEFORE INSERT trigger. What it does is, it checks all the entries in the table and sees if there is already a booking of the same doctor on the same date, for the same time. For each such row found, it increments a variable initialized by 0. If at the end of the while loop, the value of this variable is greater than zero, I cancel the query (handled by Laravel). Otherwise, I allow the query to be completed successfully.
   My question is, is it possible that if 2 people press the button at the exact same time, the trigger will run in parallel? No, right?

Hoping to find very simple and precise answers. The articles on the internet are always too confusing.

Comment: simultaneous execution depends on the underlying table, and what the queries are attempting to do, but yes - in theory, 2+ queries can execute simultaneously.

Comment: I'm talking about multiple INSERT queries on the same table. How an they run in parallel?
Query no 1. sees, the last auto increment ID is 75 and inserts a row with ID 76.
Query no 2. does the same. That will cause chaos, no? Similarly, uniqueness would not be guaranteed.

Comment: no, they'd run serially. mysql guarantees that auto_increment values are monotonic and unique, so it'd be impossible (and utterly useless in practice) if two parallel insertions would proceed simultaneously. they'd get the same ID and then you've got corrupted data. so whichever insert hits the pipe first will get the lower ID value.

Comment: @MarcB Also, the fact that triggers start with "for each row" kind of suggests inserts are queued.

Answer (score 3):

SQL code (including code in triggers) can run in parallel. However, SQL uses locks to make sure that transactions are atomic and work with consistent data. If two update statements try to update the same row of data then one of them will get a lock on that row first - preventing the other transaction from updating it for the time being. Once it's done it will release the lock then the second update would be allowed to continue on. You can also have a transaction that spans multiple statements if you need to have them all remain atomic. For `SELECT` statements they can often ignore locks (depending on the lock type) since they are just retrieving data. Two `SELECT` statements aren't going to step on each other's feet.

If two people push your theoretical button at the same time, one of them will be "first" and their transaction will go through first. That said, using a trigger here sounds like a pretty bad idea, IMO. If a doctor is never allowed to double book then use declarative RI to enforce that - not a trigger (which causes additional, and often significant, overhead.)

Comment: Okay, slight confusion here. As you said, one of them will be "first", now I'm confused how the trigger fits in here. When the "first" transaction takes place, is the trigger part of that transaction? Similarly, if there was a AFTER INSERT trigger, the trigger would first complete before the second query and then it's trigger start, right?
Also, what is a declarative RI? And we're using this to make sure if 2 people click the button at the EXACT same time, even in microseconds, we don't get a double booking.

Comment: Any triggers that fire will be part of the same transaction - which will have to completely finish before the other transaction can start to use the table. RI = Referential Integrity. Declarative RI includes things like foreign keys and table constraints - they are defined for the database/tables, not handled in code, and are much better than triggers. Too much to teach through here, so you should research.

Comment: Oh that. It won't work because I'm not just taking into account appointments starting or ending at the exact same time but also overlapping ones. 
e.g. VetID= 178, Date=2016-02-04, StartTime=14:00, EndTime= 15:00
AND VetID= 178, Date=2016-02-04, StartTime=13:30, EndTime= 15:30  overlap.
Initially I had a PHP API get do all this work but because of the delay in miliseconds, it couldn't work if the button was pressed at the EXACT same time. Thanks a lot for your help :)